# Clear a two dimensional session array

Tags: php, session

I'd like to clear a specific session, how would I go about doing that.

```
$_SESSION['files'][]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you want to unset all the array is :

```
unset ($_SESSION['files']);
```

if you want only specific entry to unset is

```
 unset ($_SESSION['files'][entry]);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could [unset](http://www.php.net/unset) the entry you want to remove :

```
unset($_SESSION['files']);
```

This will completely remove the `'files'` entry from the `$_SESSION` array.

Answer (score 3):

On addition to above answers, you can remove multiple session variables at once.

```
unset($_SESSION['file'],$_SESSION['image'],$_SESSION['video']);
```

Answer (score 1):

unset($_SESSION['files']);

use this...